# Using AJAX to check variables in database, if true, header to a certain page, on PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to check variables in the database, and if it's true, then it should make it header to a certain page, except in this testing phrase, I'm not checking any variables. I'm just testing if it'll header off to that certain page if I call the function. I started at test1.php, but it should've called the ajax function, and immediately header off to test3.php, but it didn't. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function nopassAjax(url,timeout) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             setTimeout(function() { nopassAjax(url,timeout); }, timeout);
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

> test1.php

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<script>";

echo "nopassAjax('test2.php',1000);";

echo "</script>";

?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php

//checks some stuff in the database
//if true, header off to test3.php

header("Location: test3.php");

?>
```

> test3.php

```
<?php

echo "Hello";

?>
```

Comment: What's that function `timeoutAjax()`? Where is it defined? What does it do?

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio Sorry. It was suppose to be nopassAjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work as you expect. What will happen is, when you hit `test1.php`, it will trigger `nopassAjax()`, which will make an AJAX request to `test2.php`. The `test2.php` script will call `header("Location: test3.php");` but as a response to the AJAX request, so it's the `nopassAjax()` that will receive the contents of `test3.php`, not the calling page `test1.php`. Then you `setTimeout` to start it over, so it will be in a loop and never get to where you want.

I suggest you do it a bit different. Make an AJAX call from `test1.php` to `test2.php`, but from there you return a JSON object with the information from the database. When `test1.php` receives it, it will check the data and make the decision to redirect or not.

Could be something like this:

**test1.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    setMonitoring("test2.php", 100);
});

function setMonitoring(url, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        checkData(url);
    }, timeout);
}

function checkData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json", // type of data that you're expecting back from the server
        error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(xhr.status + " - " + error);},
        success:function(data) {
            if (data.redirect) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
            }
            setMonitoring(data.nextUrlToQuery, data.timeout);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
// retrieve the information you need...

$result = array(
    "redirect"=>false,
    "nextUrlToQuery"=>"test2.php",
    "redirectTo"=>"test3.php",
    "timeout"=>1000
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

**test3.php**

```
echo "Hello";
```

In this example, when you change `redirect` to `true` in `test2.php`, the page will redirect to `test3.php`.

Comment: This is good, but is there any way I can pass the url,timeout, and the redirect url in through the parameters, somehow?

Comment: Also, is there any way to have the setTimeout in the checkData function so I can pass the timeout right through the parameters?

Comment: You can send the url and timeout through the JSON object, I have updated my answer. The `checkData()` function is already setting the timeout in the line `setMonitoring(data.timeout);`, I've just made an extra function because the same code would be called two times, there and on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: What about the url for test2.php?

Comment: This is a really good answer. I just have one more question, but I have bothered you enough, so I'll just ask it elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead an ask, it's no problem at all.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I want to put the setMonitoring javascript function inside a php function called setMonitoring, and pass the variables through the parameters of the php function to the parameters of the javascript function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80842/discussion-between-marcos-dimitrio-and-frosty).